# Intellij IDEA 11.1 eats up all available memory instead of debugging my application, what should I try?

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea

When I try to debug or run my flex application it shows "Out of memory" dialog.
I use IDEA 11.1 Ultimate and Windows 7 64x.

What I tried:

- creating a new blank project and running it - same result (Out of
  memory)
- using 64x version of IDEA - didn't help
- increasing xmx setting up to 6Gb - same result
- installing IDEA 10.5 and launching my project there - it works fine. But I really need 11.1 to run my
  project.
- uninstalling and reinstalling JRE and JDK versions 7 and 6 (not at the same time ofc) -
  didn't help
- switching from flex SDK 4.6 to 4.5 - didn't help
- reinstalling IDEA 11.1 with all the settings wiped out - didn't help!

It used to work fine before. I have no idea what could have changed.

I noticed that compilation works fine - I get a proper compiled swf file of my project that can be run in flashplayer. But right at the moment when IDEA is supposed to run the newly compiled swf it eats up all the memory.

What can be done about it? What else should I try?

I really don't understand why reinstalling IDEA didn't solve my problem. May be I didn't wipe out **all** settings?

Answer (score 2):

Try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` or even run with all the defaults after renaming [IDEA folders](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

There were also some related fixes in IDEA 11.1.3 version, [give it a try](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP).

If it doesn't help, upload `hprof` memory dump to [JetBrains FTP server](ftp://intellij.net/.uploads/) and [contact support for help](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=IDEA), see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-192 (**Memory Snapshot** section at the bottom) for details. You need to run IDEA with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` option.

Comment: Invalidate Caches didn't help. I did delete all the folders when I reinstalled IDEA - it didn't help. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open more IDEA windows? Like opening another project into new window. In such case closing the other window will not release memory. The only thing that helps me is to restart the whole IDEA application.